# How do I create a .NET WebService for File Upload

Tags: c#, web-services

I need to create a web service using the .NET platform for accepting file uploads. What are the options available for doing this in C#?
What is the best approach to use? Can please you provide me with blogs/code samples/references for further reading?

Comment: What kind of files? It makes a difference if we're talking binary or something like XML.

Comment: both binary files and xml files. both are treated the same: as binary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest approach would be [to use WebDav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) there's even a [C# library that you can embed in an application](http://www.webdavsystem.com/client) or for a server (can't find the link right now).

If you specifically have to use a WebService, it's as simple as creating a WCF Contract that accepts a Stream. Here's a [great example on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP). Enjoy.